# Outlook signature corrupted

Tags: ms-office

My Outlook for Mac signature has been displaying fine up until about 3 days ago. Potentially there was an update to MS Office around this time.

I noticed that my signature in new emails and replies displays with weird characters and symbols.

If I copy my signature and paste it into Word, the signature displays fine.

When I copy and paste into Word, the font used is Helvetica.

Answer (score 2):

I found that when editing my signature in Outlook, if I changed the font from Helvetica to Calibri the signature displayed properly again.

In Word, the signature is displayed properly in Helvetica, so it looks like Outlook has a problem using Helvetica. By default, emails are composed in Calibri.

If I compose an email and change the font to Helvetica, the text corrupts again.

This behaviour is noted in [this Microsoft Q&A thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_o365b/helvetica-neue-light-font-stopped-displaying/b9b79c39-31df-44ae-8fa6-bda6a6e4a946?auth=1).